# compiling / linking blender for windows

Tags: open-source, blender

I'm having problems linking blender for windows. I'm creating my makefiles using CMake and using the mimgw compiler (mingw32-g++.exe c++ compiler), and (mingw32-gcc.exe c compiler).

I'm getting the source from
https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/blender
https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/lib/windows
as specified in
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Doc/Building_Blender/Windows/MinGW/CMake

all the link errors are related to lib\windows\gcc
here are a few of them:

lib\windows\gcc\tiff\lib/libtiff.a(tif_pixarlog.o):(.text+0x172d): undefined reference to `deflateInit_'

lib\windows\gcc\openimageio\lib/libOpenImageIO.a(sysutil.cpp.obj):sysutil.cpp:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `GetProcessMemoryInfo@12'

lib\windows\gcc\openimageio\lib/libOpenImageIO.a(socketinput.cpp.obj):socketinput.cpp:(.text+0x45c2): undefined reference to `WSASetLastError@4'

in my lib\windows\gcc\openimageio there's a batch file (oiio-build.bat) I'm guessing this was generated by CMake

```
cmake ..\oiio\src\ -G "MinGW Makefiles" ^
    -DBUILDSTATIC=1 ^
    -DBOOST_CUSTOM=0 ^
    -DBOOST_ROOT=..\lib\windows\gcc\boost\ ^
    -DBoost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON ^
    -DLINKSTATIC=ON ^
    -DILMBASE_HALF_LIBRARIES=..\lib\windows\gcc\openexr\lib\libHalf.a ^
    -DILMBASE_IMATH_LIBRARIES=..\lib\windows\gcc\openexr\lib\libImath.a ^
    -DILMBASE_ILMTHREAD_LIBRARIES=..\lib\windows\gcc\openexr\lib\libIlmThread.a ^
    -DILMBASE_IEX_LIBRARIES=..\lib\windows\gcc\openexr\lib\libIex.a ^
    -DOPENEXR_ILMIMF_LIBRARIES=..\lib\windows\gcc\openexr\lib\libIlmImf.a ^
    -DILMBASE_INCLUDE_DIR=..\lib\windows\gcc\openexr\include ^
    -DOPENEXR_INCLUDE_DIR=..\lib\windows\gcc\openexr\include ^
    -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=..\lib\windows\zlib\include ^
    -DZLIB_LIBRARY=..\lib\windows\zlib\lib\libz.a ^
    -DPNG_LIBRARY=..\lib\windows\png\lib\libpng.a ^
    -DPNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR=..\lib\windows\png\include ^
    -DJPEG_LIBRARY=..\lib\windows\jpeg\lib\libjpeg.lib ^
    -DJPEG_INCLUDE_DIR=..\lib\windows\jpeg\include ^
    -DTIFF_LIBRARY=..\lib\windows\tiff\lib\libtiff.lib ^
    -DTIFF_INCLUDE_DIR=..\lib\windows\tiff\include ^
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=..\lib\windows\gcc\openimageio ^
    -DUSE_OPENGL=OFF ^
    -DUSE_TBB=OFF ^
    -DUSE_FIELD3D=OFF ^
    -DUSE_QT=OFF ^
    -DUSE_PYTHON=OFF ^
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
mingw32-make install
```

turns out lib\windows\gcc\oiio does not exist.

Edit: trying to compile blender 2.71 with scons, I figured out that if I don't run python from the blender folder, I get the *** No SContruct file found. error

so

with python26\python.exe scons/scons.py I get

```
ValueError: zero length field name in format:
  File "D:\blender-source\blender\SConstruct", line 54:
    EnsureSConsVersion(1,0,0)
  File "D:\blender-source\blender\scons\scons-local\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 607:
    env = self.factory()
  File "D:\blender-source\blender\scons\scons-local\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 587:
    default_env = SCons.Defaults.DefaultEnvironment()
  File "D:\blender-source\blender\scons\scons-local\SCons\Defaults.py", line 88:
    _default_env = SCons.Environment.Environment(*args, **kw)
  File "D:\blender-source\blender\scons\scons-local\SCons\Environment.py", line 1003:
    apply_tools(self, tools, toolpath)
  File "D:\blender-source\blender\scons\scons-local\SCons\Environment.py", line 107:
    env.Tool(tool)
  File "D:\blender-source\blender\scons\scons-local\SCons\Environment.py", line 1787:
    tool(self)
  File "D:\blender-source\blender\scons\scons-local\SCons\Tool\__init__.py", line 183:
    self.generate(env, *args, **kw)
  File "D:\blender-source\blender\scons\scons-local\SCons\Tool\default.py", line 41:
    SCons.Tool.Tool(t)(env)
  File "D:\blender-source\blender\scons\scons-local\SCons\Tool\__init__.py", line 183:
    self.generate(env, *args, **kw)
  File "D:\blender-source\blender\scons\scons-local\SCons\Tool\dmd.py", line 131:
    env['DLIBCOM'] = '$DLIB $_DLIBFLAGS {} $TARGET $SOURCES $_DLIBFLAGS'.format('-c' if env['PLATFORM'] == 'win32' else '')
```

with python27\python.exe scons/scons.py I get

```
scons: warning: VC version 12.0 not installed.  C/C++ compilers are most likely not set correctly.
 Installed versions are: ['9.0']
File "D:\blender-source\blender\SConstruct", line 143, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified:
  File "D:\blender-source\blender\SConstruct", line 207:
    opts.Update(env)
  File "D:\blender-source\blender\scons\scons-local\SCons\Variables\__init__.py", line 173:
    exec open(filename, 'rU').read() in {}, values
  File "<string>", line 3:
    None
  File "c:\python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710:
    errread, errwrite)
  File "c:\python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958:
    startupinfo)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake + Mingw32 hasn't been tested in a long time, but SCons + Mingw64 definitely works, as Blender build bots make nightly builds with this too: http://builder.blender.org/buildslaves/mingw64_scons_anthony

From the build slave listing you can see that there is no mingw32 slave, and I'm not sure if there'll be any in the near future.

Anyway, with SCons and Mingw64 you should have a straightforward way of running the compile process. Just make sure you have Mingw64 installed, and Python 2.6 or Python 2.7. Then check out the blender sources and lib/mingw64. Start compile process with C:\Python27\python.exe scons\scons.py in Blender source root. This should compile out of the box.

Comment: the scons.py script gives me an error: scons: *** No SConstruct  found. 

The line of code producing the error message is: 

raise SCons.Errors.UserError("No SConstruct file found.")